# How to properly create a signed webhook structure in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, sign

I have a webhook in my app (APP 1) in which another one of my apps (APP 2) needs to hit periodically, however i'm contemplating the methodology in which to securely sign these requests to make sure the webhook enpoint is only accessible by that app. I've thought of the following:

- save secret hash in env of APP1 and with every requests APP2 sends, add hash in specific header to compare against.

However i feel this approach is rather elementary in the fact that if anyone got their hands on the secret, they would be able to access the endpoint. Should be using some sort of public-secret key combination for this? any suggestions?

Comment: You could use JWTs, or roll your own token using public / private keys.

Comment: eh, JWTs require a login on the part of APP2 & thats to dynamic for what i need. Plus ill be manually providing APP2 with this key, i just want to make sure its secure in a way that anyone cant use it even if they get their hands on it, How would i do so with a public-secret key combo? @fubar

Comment: You can do the thing you noticed in the question + you can check ip of the app. To do that you need to write nginx/apache rules, to deny requests from all ips, except the one that is from the right ip address. If you can store those things in docker you can also make that you will only expose ports to internal docker containers, some that it doesn't have ports that are publicly visible

Answer (score 0):

If the systems are working on the same back-end or have access to the same database or similar it would be easiest to roll a new hash for every request and save it locally.

1. APP1 generates hash and stores in file ~/secret_app_hash
2. APP2 reads file ~/secret_app_hash and sends request with this param
3. APP1 received HTTPS request, validates the hash against the file
4. APP1 generates a new hash... basically back to step 1

This way the hash is never reused and only APP1 and APP2 have knowledge of the current hash value.

Another approach if the systems do not have the same back-end would be to periodically generate a new hash based on some secret that both apps knew: sha256(SECRET + current_time_window), similar to a 2-factor auth.

a side note to add would be that if you are using HTTPS and a POST request the param would not be readable for onlookers.